# ¿Cómo crear un BackUp de una DB de menor tamaño?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo una DB que pesa aproximadamente 29 GB en SQLSERVER 11.0, necesitó hacer un BackUp de esa misma DB que pese muchísimo menos por lo menos 1 o 2 GB.

¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto, si así es Como puedo Hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependiendo del estado de la base de datos, se puede reducir el tamaño del respaldo hasta cierto punto. Las bases de datos tienen espacio libre o sin asignar dentro de sus archivos para no tener que modificar el tamaño de los archivos constantemente. Ese espacio libre no se incluye en los respaldos, lo que genera que sean más pequeños.

La segunda parte es que los respaldos pueden ser comprimidos de manera nativa al crearlos. Puedes buscar la opción en el GUI o puedes agregar la opción al código.

```
BACKUP DATABASE <database_name> TO DISK WITH COMPRESSION (ALGORITHM = QAT_DEFLATE)
```

También hay herramientas de terceros que prometen hacer respaldos aun más pequeños que la compresión nativa. Ninguna opción te garantizará bajar de 29GB a 2GB, porque todo depende de los datos que tengas.

Hay otras herramientas como [Redgate SQL Clone](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-clone/) que permiten crear archivos pequeños que pueden ser usados para generar copias de la base de datos en distintas instancias.